# Antiforgery token validation in header using Ajax and MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, antiforgerytoken

I need to implement antiforgery validation to my MVC project. However, I am having problems with the server side.

I am using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to create the token.
Then i get the token value and include it in Ajax request.

```
// Get token
var cookie = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

// Ajax request
return $.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'post',
  headers: {
            'x-system-source': headerValue,
            'x-verification-token': cookie //verification token
           },
  data: ko.toJSON(entity),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Code below comes from microsoft documentation, however, I am not sure how to implement it. Should I create a custom attribute with the method below and add the attribute to every http request? If so, what would be the best way? Is it possible to create attribute for a controller level? I would also like to avoid repetitive code as much as possible. In addition, is there a way to unit test aniforgery validation feature to make sure that it works as expected.

I am new to the web development, and I would appreciate if you could provide code samples or point me in the right direction. Thanks for your time.

```
void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string cookieToken = "";
    string formToken = "";

    IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
    if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("x-verification-token", out tokenHeaders))
    {
        string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
        if (tokens.Length == 2)
        {
            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
    }
    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
```

Comment: Why, you do it by yourself !! ... Decorate  the endpoint method with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute, and asp will evaluate it for you automatically

Comment: @IbramReda I believe ```[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]``` could only be applied at the method level, and my application has lots of them. Is there a way to apply it at the controller level?

Comment: this article [Global Antiforgery Token Validation in ASP.NET Core](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/global-antiforgery-token-validation-in-asp-net-core) could help you